# Chatter Answers in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I need to display frequently asked chatteranswers feed (only questions need to be visible) in visualforce page.I don't want my users to post the questions or reply to questions in visualforce page.Just like Similar Questions in our Salesforce.stackexchange.com

[image]

I am using below code to display chatter answers feed in my visualforce page but it displays an ability to post questions or reply to questions

`<apex:page showHeader="false" >
      <chatteranswers:allfeeds communityId="09a90000000d1Af"/>
</apex:page>`

Anyway to do this ?

Comment: How did you style the page, and removed the sign up or sign in page that comes with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used controller to query the question object to display the title of question in visualforce page and it solved my problem to just display chatter questions in visualforce page

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I gather it should be:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" > <chatteranswers:feeds communityId="09a90000000d1Af"/> </apex:page>
```

Documentation:

```
chatteranswers:allfeeds
```

Displays the Chatter Answers application, including the feed, filters, profiles, and the Sign Up and Sign In buttons. Ext JS versions less than 3 should not be included on pages that use this component.

```
chatteranswers:feeds
```

Chatter Answers feed, which let users browse questions and articles and post replies to questions within a zone. Use with other Chatter Answers components to create a customized experience for your Chatter Answers users.